# Do 3 Boros Elite attacking trigger Battalion?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have 3 [Boros Elite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boros%20Elite) in play, and I decide to attack a player with all 3. Does it trigger Battalion? Since the card sais:

> Battalion — Whenever Boros Elite and at least two other creatures attack, Boros Elite gets +2/+2 until end of turn.

Do the other 2 Boros Elites count as the 2 other creatures? Or do I have to attack with 2 different named creatures to activate Battalion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Whenever a card refers to itself by name, it is referring to that specific instance of the card. Other cards with the same name are not affected or considered.

For a card to work in the way you describe, it would be worded significantly differently. Something along the lines of "Whenever Boros Elite and at least two other creatures not named Boros Elite...", or "Whenever Boros Elite and at least two other creatures with different names...". Examples where these restrictions are put in place are [Escaped Shapeshifter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Escaped%20Shapeshifter) and [Gifts Ungiven](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gifts%20Ungiven)

Comment: Thanks, I was playing a friendly ffa, and someone on the table told me otherwise, tried looking for some rules but couldn't find any.

Comment: the relevant rule is comprehensive rule 201.4 and 201.4a